# Where to abstract Cucumber step data properly?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I need to write a class for enforcing rules about items which may or may not be added to the same container in a warehouse, and I'd like to translate the requirements in to Cucumber before implementing it.

Each item has several attributes, such as "Item Family" (eg: electronics, book), "Item Status" (eg: main stock, faulty stock), and "Batch" (eg: 1050, 1051).

I can think of several strategies for writing a Cucumber test for this, and I'd like to know which is the recommended one:

Firstly, you could enumerate all of the attributes per product:

```
Given I have a tote containing:
  | sku    | client  | family  | status | batch | weight |
  | 100000 | Foo     | garment | main   | 1234  |     10 | 
When I add the item:
  | sku    | client  | family  | status | batch | weight |
  | 200000 | Bar     | garment | main   | 1234  |     10 |
Then I should be told there is a Client conflict
```

Secondly, you could have a basic product hard-coded, and try specifying the minimum differing attributes from it:

```
Given I have a tote containing an item that's client "Foo"
When I add an item that's client "Bar"
Then I should be told there is a Client conflict
```

This assumes the step definitions hold the basic attributes, and override them when attributes are mentioned in the steps.

Finally, you could go a further step of abstraction:

```
Given I have a tote containing an item
And I add an item with a different client
Then I should be told there's a client conflict
```

Any guidance on the correct approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) would be whichever is most readable to the non-technical members of your team.  Sit down with the QA lead and project manager, and ask them the same question.  I had a similar problem, and started with something like your first suggestion.  Then I decided it was too detailed and jumped to #3.  Then I sat down with the project manager and found out that when I was creating the data I did not need any detail, but when we changed the data (in our case updating line item values on an invoice), we wanted to see what those values were in the steps.

Chapter 6 from [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) "When Cucumbers Go Bad" was really helpful in directing to the right level of detail.  I really think you should give it a read, especially the part about coming up with an Ubiquitous Language.  I think that will help you decide on the right level of detail for your organization.

If you are tempted to use the first test, my question to you would be, "How often are you going to change those values?"  If the answer is "not very" or "never", then you should consider whether they are adding to or detracting from the readability of the test.

P.S.  I'm still reading [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book), but so far it has been extremely helpful, for example pointing me towards FactoryGirl as socjopata suggested.

Answer (score 1):

First option mentioned is the one that's most flexible and reusable. With the first approach you can cover basically any case you may need, but there are some cons, that you'll read about below.

The 2nd and 3rd options are easier to read, which is also an important factor while writing tests. Furthermore, the seem to focus on what is actually tested, i.e the key difference which "Foo" and "Bar" seem to make in that scenario/feature. And that's also preferred while writing tests.

Generally, imho writing Cucumber tests is like placing yourself between a rock and a hard place. I noticed that developers tend to reuse and over reuse cucumber steps creating hard to understand and maintain scenarios. 
The second approach requires more work in defining steps, butscenarios are cleaner and easier to read... BUT it requires more time to write a scenario as well as it produces a large steps definition base, which can be hard to maintain.

[If you really want Cucumber for bdd](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3159-testing-like-the-tsa) then I would most prolly lean to 2nd option. Just make sure you'll use `FactoryGirl` or something similar under the hood, to create generic object and overwrite only what you need at a time.

I hope that you find this useful.